# Adam optimizer error: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: optimization, error-handling, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement **Actor-Critic learning atuomation algorithm** that is not same as basic actor-critic algorithm, it's little bit changed.

Anyway, I used Adam optimizer and implemented with pytorch

when i backward TD-error for Critic first, there's no error.
However, i backward loss for Actor, the error occured.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        46             # update Actor Func
>        47             optimizer_M.zero_grad()
>   ---> 48             loss.backward()
>        49             optimizer_M.step()
>        50
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in backward(self,
>   gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
>       100                 products. Defaults to `False`.
>       101         """
>   --> 102         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
>       103 
>       104     def register_hook(self, hook):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd__init__.py in
>   backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
>   grad_variables)
>        88     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
>        89         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
>   ---> 90         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
>        91 
>        92
>
> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has
>   been modified by an inplace operation

above is the content of error

I tried to find inplace operation, but I haven't found in my written code.
I think i don't know how to handle optimizer.

Here is main code:

```
        for cur_step in range(1):   
        action = M_Agent(state, flag)  
        next_state, r = env.step(action)   

        # calculate TD Error
        TD_error = M_Agent.cal_td_error(r, next_state)

        # calculate Target
        target = torch.FloatTensor([M_Agent.cal_target(TD_error)])
        logit = M_Agent.cal_logit()
        loss = criterion(logit, target)

        # update value Func
        optimizer_M.zero_grad()
        TD_error.backward()
        optimizer_M.step()

        # update Actor Func
        loss.backward()
        optimizer_M.step()
```

Here is the agent network

```
    # Actor-Critic Agent
    self.act_pipe = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(state, 128),
                            nn.ReLU(),
                            nn.Dropout(0.5),
                            nn.Linear(128, 256),
                            nn.ReLU(),
                            nn.Dropout(0.5),
                            nn.Linear(256, num_action),
                            nn.Softmax()
                            )

     self.val_pipe = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(state, 128),
                            nn.ReLU(),
                            nn.Dropout(0.5),
                            nn.Linear(128, 256),
                            nn.ReLU(),
                            nn.Dropout(0.5),
                            nn.Linear(256, 1)
                            )


      def forward(self, state, flag, test=None):

          temp_action_prob = self.act_pipe(state)
          self.action_prob = self.cal_prob(temp_action_prob, flag)
          self.action = self.get_action(self.action_prob)
          self.value = self.val_pipe(state)

          return self.action
```

I wanna update each network respectively.

and I wanna know that Basic **TD Actor-Critic** method uses TD error for loss??
or squared error between r+V(s') and V(s) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you zero the gradients right before calling backward, after the forward propagation. Note that for [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) you need the computation graph and the intermediate results that you produce during your forward pass.

So zero the gradients **before** your TD error and target calculations! And not after you are finished your forward propagation.

```
    for cur_step in range(1):   
    action = M_Agent(state, flag)  
    next_state, r = env.step(action)   

    optimizer_M.zero_grad()  # zero your gradient here

    # calculate TD Error
    TD_error = M_Agent.cal_td_error(r, next_state)

    # calculate Target
    target = torch.FloatTensor([M_Agent.cal_target(TD_error)])
    logit = M_Agent.cal_logit()
    loss = criterion(logit, target)

    # update value Func
    TD_error.backward()
    optimizer_M.step()

    # update Actor Func
    loss.backward()
    optimizer_M.step()
```

To answer your second question, the DDPG algorithm for example uses the squared error (see the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971v2.pdf)).

Another recommendation. In many cases large parts of the value and policy networks are shared in deep actor-critic agents: you have the same layers up to the last hidden layer, and use a single linear output for value prediction and a softmax layer for the action distribution. This is especially useful if you have high dimensional visual inputs, as it act as sort of a multi-task learning, but nevertheless you can try. (As I see you have a low-dimensional state vector).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to use reinforcement learning framework for solving classification problem, I mean I have continuous state set so,  are u trying to recommend using same network and split the head parts? like kind of Dueling DQN architecture?

Comment: yes. Not sure how you use RL for classification. Anyway, the important thing is that both your policy and value networks are trying to predict related things based on the same features, this is why sharing layers make sense.

Comment: I followed your code, but still having same issue.  so confused what makes it happen

Comment: Solved. I changed each nn code to body and head parts,
then, there is no error Thanks! finally i can eat dinner

Comment: Are you sure about the `zero_grad` before the forward pass. I have trained models otherwise and also take a look at this answer https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-we-perform-optimizer-zero-grad-before-we-do-forward-pass-or-after-that/14254